# in C#, Is there a way to forcibly delete an empty folder?

Tags: c#, locking, directory

I get a message the folder is used.

It is not used by any other process (like iexplorer etc.) this happens also after restart (which will release all handles to that folder)

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: A folder gets locked when it becomes the default working directory of a process.  You don't usually have to look too far to find that process.  Usually it is an Explorer window you opened to look at the directory content.  Close it.  Or the working directory of your own program.  Stop it or assign Environment.CurrentDirectory to another one.

Comment: You are missing the point. I have been to that stage.
No process is using it, no explorer is open, no process is running there. 
It is a data folder containing files.

Answer (score 3):

> I get a message the folder is used.

This means someone is holding a lock on that folder.

> In my case it is not used by any other process

The message clearly states the opposite.

> and even it it was I would still like to be able to delete it.

No. If the folder is in use, you can't delete it.

> What is the best way to achieve this?

Use Process Explorer to find out who is holding a handle to that folder. Close it.

To clarify: If no handle existed, you could delete the folder. Together with the fact that the message states that a handle exists, the diagnosis is pretty clear: A handle exists. You have not found it yet. You have not yet provided evidence that no handle exists.

Comment: There is no process using it. Your answer is not very professional.

Comment: You seem to have a few assumptions that are false. How did you determine that no handle to that folder or a subfolder of file anywhere below it exists?

Comment: To clarify: If no handle existed, you could delete the folder. Together with the fact that the message states that a handle exists, the diagnosis is pretty clear: A handle exists. You have not found it yet. I am legitimately questioning your assumption that no handle exists and you have not yet provided any evidence that this is the case.

Comment: I was looking for a way to forcibly delete the folder even though there is a "hidden" handle to it. 
You didn't understand the questions I'm afraid